# Computing loss of Call / Stock Purchase

Tags: options

A seller of an European Call, can, subjectively have unbounded losses. This loss may be mitigated by buying the stock (covered call). In this case,, the loss will be bounded at A. How would one compute the value of A? in this case, the interest rate is 0, the initial stock price is S,  the price of call is C, and C is greater then S.

Also, there is no position at t=0. Now you sell call and buy the stock. Because S is greater then C, you borrow S - C. Additionally, at expiration, you must pay this back.

How would one even begin to compute A here? I have no clue.

Comment: Hi Sarah, welcome to Quant SE. You're question is better suited for the personal finance SE, a mod will move it for you. As a quick hint, A is the market value of the stock at the time of exercise - making the loss to the short covered call $A_T - K$ where $A_T$ is the market price of the stock at exercise and $K$ is the strike.  You observe A, not calculate it (at least in the context of your question)

Comment: I've been in contact with the people at Money and we will keep it, although the question could be improved. Sarah, is AfterWorkGuinness comment helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is the market value of the stock at the time of exercise - making the loss to the short covered call $A_T−K$ where $A_T$ is the market price of the stock at exercise and $K$ is the strike. You observe $A$, not calculate it (at least in the context of your question).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the exercise time is T , and you bought the stock at time t < T. p would be your premium

for the transaction you just mentioned , your PNL at the exercise time depends on following 2 cases :-

1. if not exercised ( ie ST < X )   :  p - St + ST , i.e. you closed your long position at exercise time.
2. if exercised ( ie ST > X ) :  p - St + X

Assuming that you sold an OTM option (which would be a fair consideration ) ,then St < X , meaning payoff for Case 2 is always

Hence , if you sold an OTM option , your loss would be capped at ( from Case 1 ) : St - ST

and if you sold an ITM option , your loss would be capped at ( from both cases )
MAX ( St - ST , St - X - p )